# Laravel encrypt password

Tags: laravel, jwt

I have a Laravel 5.6 project with Mongodb Jessengers and JWT package installed.

I am trying to encrypt the password when the user is created on the signup but I get this error:

> Indirect modification of overloaded property App\User::$attribute has
>   no effect

My User model:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value){
    $this->attribute['password'] = bcrypt($value);
}
```

My AuthController:

```
public function signup(SignUpRequest $request)
{

    $user = User::create($request->all());

    return $this->login($request);

}
```

What Am I missing?

---

Found the problem: it was

```
$this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
```

not

```
$this->attribute['password'] = bcrypt($value);
```

Comment: Try `$this->password = bcrypt($value);` instead of `$this->attribute["password"] ...`

Comment: FYI, we **hash** passwords, so we and (other) evil people cannot retrieve them. We do not **encrypt** them.

Comment: Found the problem: it was $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value); not $this->attribute['password'] = bcrypt($value);

Comment: @ThomasMoors Laravel’s bcrypt() helper function just calls the hash service :)

Comment: I know, your title says encrypt. bcrypt != encrypt